# Re applying for UK visa

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, visa-refusals

I really appreciate your quick response on this and to have full review on my refusal decision.. like u said there must be some para missing i checked the letter again, my question too the letter is all the same just i missed the point he noted ""furthermore there are large transfer and cash deposits which are 6 times your claimed salary (amount) on the 23/02/2015 and on the 15/05/2015 a cash deposit for (1,006)pounds" so the small amount of deposit were the available cash we just deposit this to our saving account as we have two accounts how to verify this? what reason should be mentioned to them that we did'not present the supported documents to declare it.

As per your review we have all of the evidences ( Death Certificate, the Cheque receipt Voucher, Copy ob Bank Cheque from the Company, Power of Attorney to my husband by his legal guardian as a trustee of what his father left, and transfer permission from the ministry that he can hold his mother and sister sponsorship as they are currently living with us in KSA) are with us in Arabic form and we translated in English with the stamp of certified translator.. do we need at attest this from chamber of commerce?

"But it would be advisable to request a different ECO for your next application. They will do this without prejudice if you ask them to; plus an ECM will review the decision if it is adverse to you." how to claim for this in our future application if u can it would b very helpful for us.

the booking we submitted was ticket bookings it was mention in the guidance of required documents.
for future application all of the personal circumstances are the same except the amount for the cost of trip we mentioned earlier my husband by mistakenly mentioned the whole family trip cost including (Plane ticket, living expenses and the money) he have for this trip instead of his personally. can we change it in each application the cost belongs to personally, It may make a wild change as compare to previous application. does it going to effect on the decision for the future application.
We already submitted Invitation letter (original) from the family members in UK. Do we submit this time the copy of invitation letter because they already have the original one.

Comment: You should really edit your existing question and add this in, rather than asking a whole new one

Comment: @Gagravarr, he wrote new stuff in an answer slot. It was placed in the LQP queue with an admonishment to ask a new question.  He did.

Comment: @GayotFow the guidance which we read before applying previous application it was mentioned to have invitation letter from the family in UK.. But the new updated guidance dated April 24 2015 on gov.uk it has changed family visa or all as one category standard visitor it doesn't show any more for invitation letter for family visit.. Can u please advice to submit it new one or not because we have only copy and time is running out for vacation and we cannot arrange the new one

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I can't see any question in here. I understand you were told to ask a new question, however I think it would be best if you edited your original question to add in all the information you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked how to request that a different ECO be assigned to your next application.  Some consulates do this by default (e.g., Russia), some do not (e.g., Nairobi) but I don't know the policy at Riyadh.  So to be sure, you can use the following steps...

1. Go online and make your fresh application.
2. Near the end of your application, they will display a page that has your new GWF number.  Write it down.
3. Complete the application and schedule your biometrics.
4. Immediately go to [UKVI's contact page](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-outside-uk), select 'email'
5. In the "What is your enquiry about?" DDL, select "I have applied for my visa and have a question"
6. In the "Question" text box, tell them that this is a fresh application following a refusal, that your refusal notice was of reduced quality, and you want a different ECO. Also tell them you want an ECM to review it because it's likely this did not happen previously. Include your prior GWF number so they can find the refusal notice and see for themselves.
7. If any part of your 'question' demonstrates sarcasm or irony or is not relentlessly civil, you will be wasting your time. They will bin it. So be careful.  In the other direction, you should avoid being gratuitously toady, they do not appreciate that either, possibly worse.  It's a business communication.
8. Give them 36 hours, then do the same thing over the telephone if need be.
9. Once it's all set, or they have (for one reason or another) refused, then attend the facilitator's office like you did the last time.

You asked if a certified translation should be accompanied with an apostille.  If it is a legal document, yes.

You asked if you should resubmit an invitation letter if they already have one from your previous application.  Yes, you should.  A fresh application starts from square 1 and makes no assumptions about what they already have or do not have.  You also asked what to do if your plans have changed wildly since your previous application.  You should state your new plans honestly, and if they are wildly out-of-sync with your previous plans you can make a BRIEF statement in Part 9 of the application.

Comment: Thank you fir your quick response which I appreciate alot.. We just have the copy of invitation letter? Does it gonna work?