# Request different entry clearance officer

Tags: visas, uk

Is it possible for me to request for a different entry clearance officer to review my UK visa application after a prior visa refusal and would that in any way have an adverse effect on the outcome of my application .

Comment: That would actually be one more reason to refuse the visa, IMO.

Comment: Please see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50627/re-applying-for-uk-visa/50630#50630

Comment: Is this about *moving* to the UK though ?

Comment: @Blackbird57 .No it's not about moving to UK. But it's  related to my previous refusal of UK visitor visa .

Comment: If you weren't a red flag before ...